# How to force a worker thread to process ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator's 'modifyHandshake' method?

Tags: quarkus

I'm modifying the handshake of Websocket by implementing ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator and overriding 'modifyHandshake', but the code is blocking and running on an IO thread,
how can I force it to run on a worker thread?

'quarkus.websocket.dispatch-to-worker=true' is working only for @serverendpoint @onopen.

I tried to annotate the 'modifyHandshake' with @Blocking but still - it's running on an IO thread.

**Expected behavior** -
modifyHandshake should be invoked on a worker thread.

**Actual behavior**
modifyHandshake invoked on an IO thread.

How to Reproduce?

```
public class WebSocketEndpointConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

  @Override 
  public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
  // executing blocking code
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  }
}
```

> WARN  [io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-7,5,main] has been blocked for 128597346 ms, time limit is 2000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked

Quarkus 2.4.1.Final

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.
i solved it by moving the code that was "blocking" from the `modifyHandshake` method into the `onOpen` method.

- i noticed that the `modifyHandshake` runs on an eventloop thread
  and basically the `onOpen` method runs on a executor thread.
- i moved all the data that i needed in order to run the "blocking" part of the code
  into the 'onOpen' method via the `config.getUserProperties()`.
- i invoked the "blocking" piece of code in the `onOpen` method and i didnt block any more.

hope it helps.